# Is using parse.com framework safe?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I would like to start using Parse.com to build a new application. I read the good documentation on their site but I am afraid there is something I might be missing out.

I understand that I can add DB data from the application. Assume I want to save some "note" to DB from my Android application - As I can see I am calling from the Android SDK a method that saves it into my DB:

```
String data = txtnote.getText().toString(); // read the note from the view
ParseObject note = new ParseObject("Notes"); // saves to notes DB
note.put(USER_NAME_KEY, username);
note.put("note", data);
note.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() 
{
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) 
    {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
});
```

I am wondering whether this code is safe? It seems that if someone tries to reverse engineer my code he can actually see some information about my parse account (when I initialize the application I use APP_ID and CLIENT_KEY). If I compare it to using a REST API installed on some server then I only send the data I want to store with the authentication key for the user?

Am I missing anything? Is there a way to completely make some king of REST API on parse.com using the cloud code? without only the need to to some operations before save?

I will appreciate your answers and if you can direct me somewhere I can learn more.

Answer (score 1):

- APP_ID and CLIENT_KEY are just used for making a connection to parse servers, not authorization to modify your data. MASTER_KEY is the crucial and important one, and you will not have that plain in your apk, so nobody can reverse engineer your apk for it. Please [see this notes on connection between client and server on parse doc site](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-connection).
- Yes, certainly you should move data sensitive operations to cloud code, and only do not-so-sensitive ops in your clients/apps. See this notes on [implementing business logic and security related ops in cloud code](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-cloudcode) using the MASTER_KEY.
- Additionally, you should consider taking advantage of [Class level](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-classes) and [object level (ACL)](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-objects) restrictions and access permissions. When you create your data model, make sure to carefully configure their access levels.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment. Is there a way to user cloud code as a REST API that I can configure to a resource URL? Instead of using the predefined operations before\after save\delete?

Comment: @user1002065 All your parse [data model can be accessed via REST api](https://parse.com/docs/rest) already

Comment: Hi, that I know, but I am asking whether I can add my own functionality in addition to the out of the box REST they provide. I want to add some custom business logic in the middle. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: @user1002065 yes it is. Add custom logic in cloud code, it gets automatically called when you REST api calls, just like non-REST api calls. You can even [use webhooks](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webhooks) if you want to customize the cloud code even further